# Interview question about salary expectations is asked with presence of technical examinator

Tags: interviewing, salary, negotiation

Interview. 4 people in the room: technical examinator (member of the team the potential employee is trying to get aboard) and manager and HR officer present + the potential employee. After the technical part the technical examinator should be gently asked to leave as its job on the interview is done. But it's not - manager/HR officer asks potential employee about salary expectations with presence of technical examinator.

Potential employee gets really uncomfortable with uncovering his negotiation strategy and salary expectations to person who may be his team mate and should not possess that information. **What should potential employee do?**

Answer (score 7):

*Answer the question* is what the candidate should do.

The three interviewers will have been empanelled to determine the suitability of the candidate(s) for the role - and that includes considering salary expectations.

Even if the technical interviewer wasn't in the room to hear the candidates answer, they will be made aware of it as soon as the interview panel reconvenes to discuss the candidate(s).

Comment: +1 The hiring committee may have to ask themselves "Is X enough better than Y to justify the difference in salary requirements?", which requires both technical evaluation and knowledge of salary expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Colleagues (or future colleagues) knowing your salary is problematic in two cases: If they make less money, and as a result get unhappy with their job and ask for more money, or if they make more money, and see you as the mug who works for cheap.

The first one isn't *your* problem. If the company makes your salary requirements visible to a future colleague, and these requirements are high, not your problem.

I would recommend that you give your requirements, and adjust a bit to the higher end, because (a) you want a good salary, and (b) you don't want to make a future colleague think that you are bad at negotiating.